# (Scheme) Check a list of item are all satisfied an logical relation

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, fold

I'm currently studying Scheme and encounter a question which description such like: Define and implement a function that takes something like a logical operator `check` and a list `xs`, then check whether that `(check a b)` evaluate to true for all two near by element `a` `b` in list `xs`.

Some example below like:

```
(check < '(15 16 17 18)) 
#t

(check > '(5)) 
#t

(check > '()) 
#t

(check (lambda (a b) (eq? b (+ a 1))) '(11 12 13))
#t

(check eq? '(4 4 5))
#f
```

In my view, I think this question similar to check a list is sorted in increasing order or not, but the implementation may have some difference.
I intend to define a recursive function involved with `foldl` and do some conditional checks, but my question is how to detect which the logical operator is and how they doing their work in my code, so anyone could help with it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: the thing to do here though is to bail out on failure as early as possible. can you do this with foldl?

Comment: "how to detect which the logical operator is" what is there to detect? you *are given it*, as an argument. you call it like `(check a b)` and it returns an `#f` or `#t` for you. and yes, if you can code the `is-sorted` predicate, this is essentially the same thing.  Aha, I see where your confusion is. You named both the function and its argument by the same name, `check`. Rename it so it is `(check-list < '(15 16 17 18))`, and it calls `(check 15 16)`, `(check 16 17)`, etc.: `(define (check-list check list) ...)`. then `check` might be `(lambda (a b) (eq? b (+ a 1)))`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two trivial cases where the function can return true, namely empty lists and lists with a single element. You check for empty lists with `null?`. You need to check first whether the list is empty, and if it isn't, if its sublist is empty (in which case there is necessarily only one element). If any of those lists is empty, the predicate trivially returns true.

Otherwise, in the general case, the predicate might return true only if `check` works for the pair of elements (that pair exists, since we ruled out lists of size 0 and 1), *and* if the sublist also satisfies the predicate.

```
(define (every-pair-check? check xs)
  (or (null? xs)
      (null? (cdr xs))
      (and (check (car xs) (cadr xs))
           (every-pair-check? check (cdr xs)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(define (check-every? check-operator lst)
  (cond ((or (null? lst) (= (length lst) 1)) #t)
        ((check-operator (car lst) (cadr lst)) (check-every? check-operator (cdr lst)))
        (else #f)))
```

This stops as soon first `#f` test occurs, thus is efficient.

I wanted to save some checks by this:

```
;; cave! Erroneous code!!
(define (check-every? check-operator lst)
  (cond ((and (null? (cdr lst)) (<= (length lst) 1)) #t)
        ((check-operator (car lst) (cadr lst)) (check-every? check-operator (cdr lst)))
        (else #f)))
```

This strategy would work in common lisp, because `(cdr '())` in common lisp returns `'()`. But in Racket/Scheme, this returns an error. How confusing! Thanks to remind me, @coredump!

My thinking was:

`(null? (cdr lst))` is a hack for `(or (null? lst) (= (length lst) 1))`,
however, if one element of `lst` is `'()`, then we would be in trouble.
But with normal number list it works. Otherwise, one should use the longer test. Now I corrected to `(and (null? (cdr lst)) (<= (length lst) 1))`,
which - due to short circuitry of `and` - tests only for `(null? (cdr lst))`, but if it is true, checks in addition, whether length of `lst` is 1 or zero. Only then, it returns `#t` for this case. So this form catches the case, that `lst` could contain a `'()` as an element somwhere else than in the last position, by still minimizing the number of tests per cycle.

But okay, since this is not possible in Racket, the first version is the shortest then ...

Comment: cdr in Scheme expects a cons cell; it is an  error to use it on empty lists.

Comment: ahh! thank you @cordump. How confusing this behaviour ... Then I have to change it back ...